# How to perform scipy test, such as normaltest, over grouped data?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, scipy

For example purposes using the pokemon dataset, I am trying to test whether the attack stats is a normal distribution for each different pokemon "type 1" group. How can I pass the groupby into scipy normaltest function?

This is what I've tried.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import normaltest

data = pd.read_csv("pokemon.csv")

type1_grp = data.groupby(['Type 1'])
type1_grp['Attack'].apply(normaltest)
```

this returns

ValueError: skewtest is not valid with less than 8 samples; 4 samples were given.

I have also tried.

```
values_per_group = [col for col_name, col in type1_grp['Attack']]
normaltest(*values_per_group)
```

but this returns the following error message:

TypeError: normaltest() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 18 were given

My ultimate goal is to test each grouped dataset whether they're normally distributed or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The first error message, "ValueError: skewtest is not valid with less than 8 samples; 4 samples were given", seems to explain the problem pretty clearly.  If one of your groups has fewer than 8 samples, you'll get an error from `skewtest`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, thanks for your help. Sorry, I am still learning to read the error messages. I am guessing from here, I need to include an if statement excluding the group with sample size less than 8. Could you please help guide me on how to do this?